# calculating the mean of numeric values in a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples, mean

I'm new to Python and stumbled upon the following issue: I have two lists (listA and listB) consisting of tuples ('str', float) and I have to calculate the mean of the float values for each list.

```
groups = ['A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A']
scores = [0.2, 0.3, 0.9, 1.1, 2.2, 2.9, 0.0, 0.7, 1.3, 0.3]

list_groups_scores = list(zip(groups,scores))
list_groups_scores.sort()
    
print(list_groups_scores)


listA = list_groups_scores[0:4]
listB = list_groups_scores[5:9]
print(listA, listB)
```

Can anyone help?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Loop in group array and sum values for current group (use dictionary to save the result and the number of values. Then for each entry in dict, dive the sum by the number of entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dict to hold the group and the scores

```
from collections import defaultdict

groups = ['A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A','K']
scores = [0.2, 0.3, 0.9, 1.1, 2.2, 2.9, 0.0, 0.7, 1.3, 0.3,1]
data = defaultdict(list)
for g,s in zip(groups,scores):
  data[g].append(s)
for grp,scores in data.items():
  print(f'{grp} --> {sum(scores)/len(scores)}')
```

output

```
A --> 0.725
B --> 1.1666666666666667
K --> 1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Two different points, each has several solutions.

**I. How th get back the floats from the tuples in the list**

- Using the unpack idiom and list comprehension

  ```
  float_list = [v for i, v in listA]
  ```
- Pure Python

  ```
  float_list = []
  for item in listA:
      float_list.append(item[1])
  ```

**II. How to calculate the mean**

- Import `mean` from some module

  - `from Numpy import mean`
  - `from statistics import mean`
- Using `sum` and `length`

  Sum on values in list and divide by list length

  ```
  mean = sum(v in a_list) / len(a_list)
  ```
- Pure Python

  Loop to aggregate values and count to length

  ```
  aggregate = 0
  length = 0
  for item in a_list:
       aggregate += item
       length += 1
  mean = aggregate / length
  ```

  Note: `aggregate` chosen for two reasons:

  ```
  - avoiding the use of a built-in function
  - generalizing the name of the variable, for example, a function other than addition could be used.
  ```

**Solution**

Solutions can be a mix of steps I and step II, but ad'hoc solutions can spare the construction of the intermediary list (`float_list` in the examples of part I)

For example:

- Using `sum` and `length`

  Sum on unpacked values in list and divide by list length

  ```
  mean = sum(v in float_list) / len(float_list)
  ```

  Note: `v in float_list` does not create a list; it is a *generator* bringing the floats on demand.
- Pure Python

  Loop to aggregate values and count to length

  ```
  aggregate = 0
  length = 0
  for item in  listA:
       aggregate += item[1]
       length += 1
  mean = aggregate / length
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
sum = 0
ii=0
for sub in listA:
    ii+=1
    i=sub[1]
    sum = sum + i
avg=sum/ii
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = lambda x:[i[1] for i in x]

print(sum(s(listA))/len(listA))

print(sum(s(listB))/len(listB))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a special type of loop in python that looks like this.

```
listANumbers = [i[1] for i in listA]
```

It loops through every element in listA and sets every element[1] to a new list.

result:

```
[0.2, 0.3, 1.1, 1.3]
```

You can then take the sum and average of the new list.

```
listANumbers = [i[1] for i in listA]
meanA = sum(listANumbers) / len(listANumbers)
```